# Get a list of tensor from masked indices

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I'm trying to get a list of tensors based on different group,

e.g.,

```
x = tensor([ 0.3018, -0.0079,  1.4995, -1.4422,  1.6007])

indices = torch.tensor([0,0,1,1,2])

res = func(x,indices)
```

I want my result to be

```
res= [[0.3018, -0.0079], [1.4995, -1.4422], [1.6007]]
```

I'm wondering how can I achieve this result, I checked `gather` and `index_select`,
but I can't get the result like above.

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like you could do a `for` loop. The way you expected your output wouldn't allow vectorization anyway.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```py
res = [x[indices == i_] for i_ in indices.unique()]
```